# C# TableAdapter Fill/Get by Multiple IDs

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2013, tableadapter

I'm faced with a little problem. The situation is:
I have a MSSQL table which contains `IDs` (int, identity, primarykey), and `names` (string).
This table is huge, so i don't want to fill the entire dataset just for one LINQ-query.
I have a search algorithm, which fills a `List<int>` with more than one ID.

I want to load the matching rows in a datagridview with the following code:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = tbl_WorklistTableAdapter.GetDataByID(ids_here);
```

But i can't handle multiple IDs, just a single. `The GetDataByID()` code needs to be this (i think):

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[NAME]
  FROM [DataBase].[dbo].[tbl_Namelist]
  WHERE ID IN (@searchterm)
```

However `WHERE ID IN` accepts comma-separated ints, like `1,2,3`. But the @variable is just one int.

How should i convert string to ints?

Thank you, and sorry for bad eng. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you need to change in sql so you need to generate one temp table for comma separated id and apply condition in the your query.

**Like:-**

```
DECLARE @variables VARCHAR(200) = @searchterm -- Your Variable
CREATE TABLE #temp(ID NUMERIC) DECLARE @temp VARCHAR(200)
SET @temp = @variables WHILE LEN(@temp) > 0 BEGIN DECLARE @t1 VARCHAR(200)
IF   CHARINDEX(',',@temp) > 0 
 BEGIN
   SET @t1 = SUBSTRING(@temp,0,CHARINDEX(',',@temp))
   INSERT INTO #TEMP SELECT @t1
   SET @temp = SUBSTRING(@temp,CHARINDEX(',',@temp)+1,len(@temp)) 
 END 
 ELSE 
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO #TEMP SELECT @temp
   SET @temp = '' 
   END 
END  
SELECT [ID]
  ,[NAME]
FROM [DataBase].[dbo].[tbl_Namelist]
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM #temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in function [SPLIT_STRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function:

```
SELECT [ID], [NAME]
FROM [DataBase].[dbo].[tbl_Namelist]
WHERE ID IN (SELECT VALUE FROM SPLIT_STRING(@searchterm,','))
```

This only works on Compatibility level 130 or greater.

If you are on an older version of SQL Server you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58505547/3169805), which defines an equivalent function:

```
SELECT [ID], [NAME]
FROM [DataBase].[dbo].[tbl_Namelist]
WHERE ID IN (SELECT VALUE FROM fn_split_string(@searchterm,','))
```

Comment: I'm adding this years later because Google still takes you to this question.