# STRING_SPLIT in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, split, sql-server-2012

I have this parameter

```
@ID varchar = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20'
```

I want to do something to split the comma-separated values.

The `string_split` function doesn't work and I get this error:

> The STRING_SPLIT function is available only under compatibility level 130

and I try to alter my database and set the compatibility to 130 but I don't have a permission for this change.

Comment: Here is somewhat old-fashioned solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-t-sql

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Other approach is to use `XML` Method with `CROSS APPLY` to split your Comma Separated Data :

```
SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') DATA
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@ID, ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
) AS A
CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a);
```

Result :

```
DATA
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

Example :

```
DECLARE @ID NVARCHAR(300)= '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20';
DECLARE @Marks NVARCHAR(300)= '0,1,2,5,8,9,4,6,7,3,5,2,7,1,9,4,0,2,5,0';
DECLARE @StudentsMark TABLE
(id    NVARCHAR(300),
 marks NVARCHAR(300)
); 
--insert into @StudentsMark 
;WITH CTE
     AS (
     SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') id,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY
                             (
                                 SELECT NULL
                             )) RN
     FROM
     (
         SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@ID, ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
     ) AS A
     CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a)),
     CTE1
     AS (
     SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') marks,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY
                             (
                                 SELECT NULL
                             )) RN
     FROM
     (
         SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@Marks, ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
     ) AS A
     CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a))
     INSERT INTO @StudentsMark
            SELECT C.id,
                   C1.marks
            FROM CTE C
                 LEFT JOIN CTE1 C1 ON C1.RN = C.RN;
SELECT *
FROM @StudentsMark;
```

Answer (score 14):

Inline function based on [Yogesh Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46902994/6165594) and [Salman A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58522693/6165594) answers:

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_split_string]
(
    @string    nvarchar(max),
    @delimiter nvarchar(max)
)
/*
    The same as STRING_SPLIT for compatibility level < 130
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
*/
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
(
    SELECT 
      --ROW_NUMBER ( ) over(order by (select 0))                            AS id     --  intuitive, but not correect
        Split.a.value('let $n := . return count(../*[. << $n]) + 1', 'int') AS id
      , Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')                                 AS value
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@string, @delimiter, '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
    ) AS a
    CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a)
)
```

Example:

```
DECLARE @ID NVARCHAR(300)= 'abc,d,e,f,g';
select * from fn_split_string(@ID,',')

-- If you need exactly string_split functionality (without id column):
select value from fn_split_string(@ID,',')
```

Comment: Worked great except it was returning two columns and I wanted to use it in an IN so I needed just the values. To really match the new built-in function it should only return the values, so I removed the id from the select statement in the function body.

Comment: @CalebMauer, yes, in case you need exactly `string_split` functionality, you have to comment `id` row.
`id` is usefull/comfortable when you have to insert into one table two columns from two strings (`'a1,b1,c1'` to `Column1` and  `'a2,b2,c2'` to `Column2` for instance).

Answer (score 5):

Another approach would be to use CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING in a WHILE:

```
DECLARE @IDs VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @Number VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @charSpliter CHAR;

SET @charSpliter = ',';
SET @IDs = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20' + @charSpliter;

WHILE CHARINDEX(@charSpliter, @IDs) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @Number = SUBSTRING(@IDs, 0, CHARINDEX(@charSpliter, @IDs));
    SET @IDs = SUBSTRING(@IDs, CHARINDEX(@charSpliter, @IDs) + 1, LEN(@IDs));

    PRINT @Number;

END;
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternate function to String_Split for older versions of SQL Server

Create this Function in your Database

```sql
Create Function dbo.Test_Split( @string varchar(4000))
Returns
@Result Table (value varchar(100))
As
Begin
    declare @len int, @loc int = 1
    While @loc <= len(@string) 
    Begin
        Set @len = CHARINDEX(',', @string, @loc) - @loc
        If @Len < 0 Set @Len = len(@string)
        Insert Into @Result Values (SUBSTRING(@string,@loc,@len))
        Set @loc = @loc + @len + 1
    End
    Return
End
```

How to Use

```sql
Select
    *
From
    dbo.Test_Split('First,Second,Third,Fourth')
```

Answer (score 2):

For those looking how to transform multi-line text into rows, here is a code based on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46902994/6360002):

```
declare @text varchar(max) = 'line0
line1
line2'

select split.a.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') data
from
(
    select cast('<x>' + replace(@text, char(13) + char(10), '</x><x>') + '</x>' as xml) as string
) as a
cross apply string.nodes('/x') as split(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you [al3x-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4149929/al3x-m).
i create this function for reused in many time.

```
CREATE FUNCTION STRING_SPLIT_POLYFILL2016 (
    @string NVARCHAR(4000)
    ,@separator NVARCHAR(4000)
    )
RETURNS @T TABLE (ColName VARCHAR(4000))
AS
BEGIN
    /*
pitt phunsanit
polyfill of STRING_SPLIT in SQL Server 2016
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902892/string-split-in-sql-server-2012
*/
    DECLARE @Number VARCHAR(4000);

    SET @string = @string + @separator;

    WHILE CHARINDEX(@separator, @string) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Number = SUBSTRING(@string, 0, CHARINDEX(@separator, @string));
        SET @string = SUBSTRING(@string, CHARINDEX(@separator, @string) + 1, LEN(@string));

        INSERT INTO @T (ColName)
        VALUES (@Number)
    END

    RETURN
END
```

-- DEMO

```
DECLARE @IDS NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @IDS = 'pitt,phunsanit,01,02,03,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,พิชญ์,พันธุ์สนิท'

SELECT *
FROM STRING_SPLIT_POLYFILL2016(@IDS, ',')
```

[Live demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=61f44fe72003f01f273dc4849ad9aa28)

Answer (score 1):

A little variation of @Al3x_M's polyfill, when it is not possible to change the database compatibility level : I use a `TABLE` variable to store the list of value, for using them later in another query:

```
DECLARE @IDs VARCHAR(500);
SET @IDs = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,2a0' ;

declare @list TABLE (id int);
DECLARE @Number int, @idx int
DECLARE @charSpliter CHAR;

SET @charSpliter = ','
SET @IDs = @IDs + @charSpliter;
set  @idx = 0

WHILE (1 = 1)
    BEGIN
        set  @idx =  CHARINDEX(@charSpliter, @IDs)
        if (@idx is NULL or @idx <= 0) break;

        BEGIN TRY
        SET @Number = SUBSTRING(@IDs, 0, @idx)
        SET @IDs = SUBSTRING(@IDs, @idx + 1, LEN(@IDs))

        insert @list select convert(int, @Number)
    END TRY  
    BEGIN CATCH 
        break
    END CATCH  
END

-- @list available for the next query...
select * from  @list
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can try this function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1
       
        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)
        
    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

EXAMPLE

```
DECLARE @StringArray VARCHAR(max)
        Set  @StringArray= 'a,b,c,d,f';
select * from dbo.fnSplitString(@StringArray,',')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a another method to split string. It is faster I used. especially to split log string. more information please refer: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[UFN_STRING_SPLIT]
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a 
      CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
```

test code:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql ='ZJNB015,ZJNB014,ZJNB008,ZJNB005,ZJJX018,ZJJX013,ZJJX011,ZJJX007,ZJHZ092,ZJHZ090,ZJHZ088,ZJHZ086,ZJHZ066,ZJHZ063,ZJHZ061,ZJHZ058,ZJHZ047,ZJHZ009,YNKM156,YNKM155,YNKM153,YNKM152,YNKM151,YNKM150,YNKM148,YNKM147,YNKM146,YNKM144,YNKM143,YNKM142,YNKM141,YNKM133,YNKM132,YNKM130,YNKM128,YNKM127,YNKM125,YNKM124,YNKM098,YNKM097,YNKM093,YNKM092,YNKM085,YNKM079,YNKM059,YNKM057,YNKM025,YNKM019,YNKM017,YNKM015,YNKM013,YNKM012,YNKM011,YNKM009,YNKM008,YNKM007,YNKM006,YNKM005,XJWLMQ047,XJWLMQ038,XJWLMQ022,XJWLMQ014,TJTJ129,TJTJ104,TJTJ090,TJTJ089,TJTJ085,TJTJ084,TJTJ065,TJTJ061,TJTJ058,TJTJ055,TJTJ050,TJTJ038,TJTJ036,TJTJ026,TJTJ024,TJTJ022,TJTJ021,TJTJ019,TJTJ018,TJTJ015,TJTJ009,TJTJ008,TJTJ003,SXYC001,SXXA037,SXXA027,SXXA021,SXXA020,SXXA013,SXXA012,SXXA011,SXXA005,SXXA002,SXTY044,SXTY039,SXTY032,SXTY024,SXTY022,SXTY012,SXTY009,SXTY008,SXDT001,SX006222,SX006183,SX006176,SX006152,SX005976,SX005937,SX005799,SX005668,SX005407,SX000825,SX000403,SX000194,SX000171,SX000130,SX000081,SX000078,SX000045,SX000036,SX000018,SX000003,SNC001,SHSH167,SHSH165,SHSH164,SHSH163,SHSH162,SHSH161,SHSH158,SHSH157,SHSH155,SHSH154,SHSH153,SHSH148,SHSH147,SHSH144,SHSH137,SHSH132,SHSH125,SHSH123,SHSH122,SHSH119,SHSH118,SHSH112,SHSH106,SHSH095,SHSH094,SHSH092,SHSH075,SHSH068,SHSH051,SHSH034,SHSH029,SHSH023,SHSH014,SHSH011,SHSH010,SHSH008,SHSH006,SHSH005,SHSH004,SDWZB006,SDWTA002,SDWTA001,SDWJN022,SDWH003,SDQD020,SDQD008,SDJN016,SDJN008,SDCD064,SDCD062,SDCD059,SCYB007,SCNJ010,SCNC022,SCMY029,SCMY028,SCMY014,SCLZ019,SCLS016,SCGY010,SCDY011,SCDY007,SCCD200,SCCD199,SCCD198,SCCD197,SCCD196,SCCD195,SCCD194,SCCD193,SCCD192,SCCD191,SCCD188,SCCD187,SCCD186,SCCD185,SCCD183,SCCD182,SCCD181,SCCD179,SCCD176,SCCD174,SCCD173,SCCD172,SCCD171,SCCD166,SCCD165,SCCD164,SCCD163,SCCD162,SCCD161,SCCD160,SCCD158,SCCD157,SCCD152,SCCD150,SCCD144,SCCD136,SCCD123,SCCD117,SCCD110,SCCD102,SCCD080,SCCD053,SCCD051,SCCD040,SCCD031,SCCD025,SCCD020,SCCD019,SCCD017,SCCD013,SCCD004,SCCD003,SCCD002,QHXN006,QHXN005,QHXN004,NMHHHT003,NMHHHT002,NMBT001,LNSY034,LNSY017,LNSY010,LNSY006,LNSY002,LNSY001,LNJZ008,LNDL030,LNDL016,LNDL008,LNDL005,LNDL002,LNAS008,LNAS004,JXYC109,JXYC065,JXNC1001,JXNC098,JXNC082,JXNC073,JXNC069,JXNC067,JXNC066,JXNC065,JXNC064,JXNC063,JXNC062,JXNC045,JXNC026,JXNC003,JXJJ063,JXJJ061,JXJJ012,JXGZ110,JXGZ106,JXGZ1006,JXGZ1004,JXGZ085,JXGZ068,JXGZ031,JXGZ015,JXGZ011,JXGZ007,JXFZ101,JSZJ010,JSZJ002,JSYZ082,JSYZ081,JSYZ080,JSYZ076,JSYZ075,JSYZ074,JSYZ069,JSYZ067,JSXZ071,JSXZ070,JSXZ068,JSXZ067,JSXZ066,JSXZ064,JSXZ063,JSXZ058,JSXZ057,JSXZ053,JSXZ052,JSXZ051,JSXZ050,JSXZ049,JSXZ046,JSXZ043,JSXZ025,JSXZ022,JSXZ020,JSXZ012,JSXZ011,JSXZ007,JSWX057,JSWX056,JSWX055,JSWX053,JSWX052,JSWX051,JSWX050,JSWX047,JSWX045,JSWX042,JSWX041,JSWX038,JSWX032,JSWX030,JSWX029,JSWX016,JSWX014,JSSZ062,JSSZ061,JSSZ056,JSSZ054,JSSZ052,JSSZ049,JSSZ034,JSSZ031,JSSZ030,JSSZ026,JSSZ023,JSSZ020,JSSZ004,JSSZ002,JSSQ022,JSNT014,JSNT013,JSNJ32,JSNJ093,JSNJ092,JSNJ089,JSNJ087,JSNJ086,JSNJ085,JSNJ084,JSNJ081,JSNJ079,JSNJ078,JSNJ075,JSNJ074,JSNJ071,JSNJ070,JSNJ069,JSNJ066,JSNJ065,JSNJ064,JSNJ063,JSNJ062,JSNJ061,JSNJ052,JSNJ042,JSNJ028,JSNJ026,JSNJ021,JSNJ017,JSNJ015,JSNJ013,JSNJ009,JSLYG104,JSLYG001,JSKS003,JSKS002,JSHA027,JSHA026,JSHA025,JSHA021,JNDZ2,JLJL001,JLCC045,JLCC033,JLCC024,JLCC016,JLCC010,JLCC003,IN995904,IN994165,IN994017,IN976180,IN974591,IN0510360,IN018611,IN017781,IN0176312,IN0174673,IN016272,IN0157453,IN0153814,IN0152570,IN0139922,IN0139920,IN0136951,IN0136160,IN012803,IN0126336,IN0123703,IN011648,IN0115515,IN0099299,IN0092308,IN007290,IN007253,IN006969,IN0066740,IN005618,IN005452,IN005309,IN0051963,IN005110,IN005109,IN005106,IN0050678,IN004129,IN004113,IN004103,IN0032362,IN0028960,IN0028115,IN0023061,IN002245,IN002214,IN0021930,IN002072,IN002035,IN001925,IN001827,IN0017119,IN001708,IN001620,IN001613,IN001611,IN001598,IN001577,IN001520,IN001454,IN001391,IN001374,IN001371,IN001367,IN001365,IN001360,IN001357,IN001345,IN001340,IN001335,IN001333,IN001300,IN001255,IN001248,IN001247,IN001240,IN001225,IN001211,IN001183,IN001181,IN001175,IN001173,IN001144,IN001096,IN001085,IN001073,IN0010637,IN001008,IN000997,IN000995,IN000984,IN000963,IN000958,IN000955,IN000930,IN000925,IN000885,IN000856,IN000813,IN000811,IN000772,IN000408,IN000334,IN000332,IN000325,IN000314,IN000267,IN000217,IN000148,IN000147,IN000145,IN000144,IN000126,IN000118,IN000117,IN000115,IN000114,IN000111,IN000107,IN000092,IN000086,IN000081,IN000073,IN000057,IN000051,IN000029,IN000026,IN000021,IN000018,IN000013,IN000006,HUNZZ077,HUNZZ062,HUNZZ003,HUNYY058,HUNYY002,HUNXT063,HUNSY072,HUNHY076,HUNHY061,HUNHY049,HUNHY008,HUNHY002,HUNHY001,HUNHH080,HUNCS090,HUNCS086,HUNCS085,HUNCS084,HUNCS082,HUNCS081,HUNCS079,HUNCS078,HUNCS076,HUNCS074,HUNCS069,HUNCS061,HUNCS051,HUNCS050,HUNCS046,HUNCS044,HUNCS043,HUNCS037,HUNCS032,HUNCS031,HUNCS012,HUNCS003,HUNCD059,HNZZ1004,HNZZ070,HNZZ064,HNZZ061,HNZZ060,HNZZ056,HNZZ055,HNZZ054,HNZZ052,HNZZ051,HNZZ049,HNZZ037,HNZZ035,HNZZ012,HNZZ011,HNZZ009,HNZZ008,HNZZ004,HNZZ003,HNXX065,HNXX008,HNXX002,HNNY086,HNNY085,HNNY084,HNNY080,HNLY1008,HNLY1007,HNLY071,HNLY068,HNLY050,HNLH075,HNLH041,HNKF1005,HNKF005,HNKF004,HNAY082,HLJHRB033,HLJHRB030,HLJHRB018,HLJHRB012,HLJHRB006,HBYC105,HBYC010,HBYC008,HBYC001,HBXY027,HBXY026,HBXY025,HBXY022,HBXY018,HBXY015,HBXY009,HBXN010,HBXN009,HBXN005,HBXG021,HBXG020,HBXG019,HBXG016,HBXG007,HBWH219,HBWH218,HBWH217,HBWH214,HBWH213,HBWH212,HBWH207,HBWH206,HBWH205,HBWH203,HBWH202,HBWH193,HBWH190,HBWH188,HBWH187,HBWH183,HBWH181,HBWH176,HBWH173,HBWH168,HBWH166,HBWH164,HBWH163,HBWH162,HBWH158,HBWH154,HBWH151,HBWH142,HBWH139,HBWH138,HBWH133,HBWH131,HBWH128,HBWH124,HBWH121,HBWH116,HBWH112,HBWH111,HBWH105,HBWH102,HBWH099,HBWH098,HBWH086,HBWH084,HBWH080,HBWH077,HBWH059,HBWH045,HBWH039,HBWH033,HBWH028,HBWH027,HBWH025,HBWH023,HBWH022,HBWH019,HBWH012,HBWH008,HBSZ003,HBSY004,HBSY003,HBSY001,HBJZ019,HBJZ018,HBJZ017,HBJZ013,HBJZ004,HBJM005,HBHS032,HBHS031,HBHS029,HBHS026,HBHS025,HBHS020,HBHS018,HBHS016,HBHS015,HBHG008,HBEZ001,HBBD003,GZGY059,GZGY058,GZGY057,GZGY056,GZGY055,GZGY053,GZGY050,GZGY044,GZGY041,GZGY039,GZGY038,GZGY037,GZGY033,GZGY013,GZGY010,GZGY007,GZGY005,GZGY004,GZGY003,GXYL019,GXNN038,GXNN037,GXNN033,GXNN032,GXNN031,GXNN030,GXNN018,GXNN017,GXNN007,GXNN004,GXLZ021,GXLZ020,GXLZ019,GXLZ018,GXLZ017,GXLZ014,GXLZ007,GXLZ006,GXLZ004,GXGL040,GXGL038,GXGL036,GXGL035,GXGL034,GXGL032,GXGL031,GXGL030,GXGL013,GXGL012,GXGL011,GXGL002,GXGG002,GXBH003,GXBH001,GSLZ028,GSLZ025,GSLZ015,GSLZ006,GSLZ005,GSLZ004,GSLZ003,GSLZ002,GDZS018,GDZS017,GDZS016,GDZS014,GDZS001,GDZH008,GDZH007,GDZH001,GDSZ047,GDSZ046,GDSZ045,GDSZ044,GDSZ043,GDSZ042,GDSZ040,GDSZ038,GDSZ037,GDSZ036,GDSZ032,GDSZ017,GDSZ013,GDSZ004,GDSZ002,GDSZ001,GDJY011,GDJY010,GDJY009,GDJM010,GDJM009,GDHZ012,GDHZ011,GDHZ008,GDGZ089,GDGZ088,GDGZ087,GDGZ086,GDGZ085,GDGZ084,GDGZ083,GDGZ082,GDGZ081,GDGZ079,GDGZ077,GDGZ076,GDGZ075,GDGZ074,GDGZ073,GDGZ071,GDGZ070,GDGZ068,GDGZ066,GDGZ064,GDGZ062,GDGZ061,GDGZ047,GDGZ042,GDGZ023,GDGZ021,GDGZ006,GDGZ004,GDFS039,GDFS038,GDFS033,GDFS031,GDFS021,GDFS017,GDFS004,GDFS001,GDDW023,GDDW008,GDDW003,GDDG075,GDDG074,GDDG073,GDDG071,GDDG067,GDDG059,GDDG039,FJZZ029,FJZZ028,FJZZ025,FJZZ001,FJXM064,FJXM063,FJXM062,FJXM022,FJXM016,FJXM010,FJQZ025,FJQZ024,FJQZ023,FJQZ022,FJQZ017,FJQZ012,FJPT004,FJPT003,FJPT001,FJLY001,FJFZ043,FJFZ041,FJFZ040,FJFZ037,FJFZ033,FJFZ022,DW407806,DW400478,DW399077,DW395285,DW381615,DW377180,DW368707,DW364714,DW143916,DW143060,DW137429,DW13694,DW126529,DW121990,DW121108,DW118851,DW106708,DW102873,DW098474,DW097703,DW087154,DW083144,DW078807,DW077430,DW071447,DW069691,DW066354,DW065966,DW059329,DW048326,DW042775,DW037572,DW024946,DW024855,DW021684,DW018021,DW014837,DW014059,DW014057,DW014033,DW013990,DW013982,DW013967,DW013948,DW013913,DW013896,DW013889,DW013874,DW013847,DW013816,DW013798,DW013761,DW013742,DW013740,DW013730,DW013658,DW013601,DW013560,DW013529,DW013522,DW013509,DW013442,DW013438,DW013346,DW013341,DW013327,DW013318,DW013256,DW013245,DW013228,DW013211,DW010285,DW004292,CQCQ142,CQCQ140,CQCQ138,CQCQ137,CQCQ136,CQCQ135,CQCQ134,CQCQ132,CQCQ131,CQCQ125,CQCQ122,CQCQ121,CQCQ117,CQCQ116,CQCQ113,CQCQ110,CQCQ108,CQCQ107,CQCQ106,CQCQ101,CQCQ099,CQCQ097,CQCQ094,CQCQ092,CQCQ086,CQCQ085,CQCQ084,CQCQ083,CQCQ082,CQCQ081,CQCQ080,CQCQ077,CQCQ067,CQCQ061,CQCQ044,CQCQ039,CQCQ029,CQCQ028,CQCQ026,CQCQ022,CQCQ021,CQCQ018,CQCQ006,CQCQ005,CQCQ002,BXJWLMQ1364,BXJWLMQ1300,BXJWLMQ1242,BXJWLMQ1082,BXJWLMQ1042,BXJWLMQ0787,BXJWLMQ0682,BXJWLMQ0545,BXJWLMQ0532,BXJWLMQ0528,BTJTJ1575,BTJTJ1552,BTJTJ1486,BTJTJ1469,BTJTJ1467,BTJTJ1408,BTJTJ1398,BTJTJ1327,BTJTJ1209,BTJTJ1200,BTJTJ1180,BTJTJ1178,BTJTJ1062,BTJTJ0958,BTJTJ0942,BTJTJ0852,BTJTJ0793,BTJTJ0671,BTJTJ0649,BTJTJ0614,BTJTJ0603,BTJTJ0536,BTJTJ0530,BTJTJ0527,BTJTJ0488,BTJTJ0448,BTJTJ0422,BTJTJ0184,BTJTJ0064,BSXYC0643,BSXXY1464,BSXXY1406,BSXXY0813,BSXXY0564,BSXXA1623,BSXXA1617,BSXXA1612,BSXXA1611,BSXXA1610,BSXXA1593,BSXXA1592,BSXXA1587,BSXXA1586,BSXXA1574,BSXXA1573,BSXXA1569,BSXXA1568,BSXXA1567,BSXXA1537,BSXXA1517,BSXXA1516,BSXXA1515,BSXXA1514,BSXXA1513,BSXXA1511,BSXXA1503,BSXXA1496,BSXXA1492,BSXXA1483,BSXXA1450,BSXXA1449,BSXXA1446,BSXXA1442,BSXXA1417,BSXXA1384,BSXXA1367,BSXXA1363,BSXXA1357,BSXXA1356,BSXXA1355,BSXXA1354,BSXXA1320,BSXXA1304,BSXXA1284,BSXXA1277,BSXXA1276,BSXXA1270,BSXXA1268,BSXXA1257,BSXXA1254,BSXXA1253,BSXXA1219,BSXXA1206,BSXXA1203,BSXXA1027,BSXXA1024,BSXXA1021,BSXXA1020,BSXXA1011,BSXXA0981,BSXXA0980,BSXXA0957,BSXXA0924,BSXXA0880,BSXXA0860,BSXXA0846,BSXXA0844,BSXXA0828,BSXXA0817,BSXXA0789,BSXXA0738,BSXXA0404,BSXXA0211,BSXXA0050,BSXWN1325,BSXTY1630,BSXTY1585,BSXTY1584,BSXTY1570,BSXTY1551,BSXTY1505,BSXTY1466,BSXTY1453,BSXTY1303,BSXTY1259,BSXTY1229,BSXTY0796,BSXTY0795,BSXTY0769,BSXTY0768,BSXTY0573,BSXTY0547,BSXTY0067,BSXSZ1402,BSXLF1326,BSXBJ1628,BSDZZ1578,BSDZB1590,BSDZB1572,BSDZB1542,BSDZB1447,BSDZB1298,BSDZB0565,BSDYT1522,BSDYT1199,BSDYT0759,BSDYT0748,BSDYT0718,BSDWH0465,BSDWH0464,BSDWF1039,BSDWF0952,BSDTZ1391,BSDTA1558,BSDTA1530,BSDTA1045,BSDRZ1278,BSDQD1445,BSDQD1444,BSDQD1407,BSDQD1365,BSDQD1280,BSDQD1279,BSDQD1233,BSDQD1018,BSDQD0666,BSDQD0584,BSDLY1543,BSDLY1190,BSDJN1559,BSDJN1509,BSDJN1508,BSDJN1506,BSDJN1421,BSDJN1416,BSDJN1349,BSDJN1236,BSDJN1129,BSDJN0960,BSDJN0954,BSDJN0785,BSDJN0560,BSDJN0469,BSDJN0109,BSDJN0070,BSDHZ0826,BSDDZ1624,BQHXN1615,BQHXN1564,BQHXN1512,BQHXN1405,BQHXN1347,BQHXN1346,BQHXN1138,BQHXN1095,BQHXN0841,BQHXN0825,BQHXN0770,BQHXN0722,BQHXN0540,BQHXN0533,BNXZW0832,BNXYC1563,BNXYC1562,BNXYC1561,BNXYC1510,BNXYC1463,BNXYC1426,BNXYC1404,BNXYC1344,BNXYC1258,BNXYC1216,BNXYC1167,BNXYC1092,BNXYC1084,BNXYC0903,BNXYC0884,BNXYC0831,BNXYC0626,BNXYC0562,BNXYC0432,BNXYC0392,BNXYC0325,BNXWZ0498,BNXWZ0497,BNMHHHT0716,BNMHHHT0566,BNMHHHT0423,BNMHHHT0393,BNMHHHT0266,BNMCF1220,BNMCF0928,BNMBT1385,BNMBT1335,BNMBT0715,BLNTL0875,BLNSY1603,BLNSY1539,BLNSY1491,BLNSY1471,BLNSY1455,BLNSY1334,BLNSY1046,BLNSY0987,BLNSY0949,BLNSY0702,BLNSY0698,BLNSY0574,BLNSY0490,BLNKY0641,BLNJZ1547,BLNJZ1523,BLNJZ1498,BLNJZ1137,BLNJZ1034,BLNJZ0644,BLNDL1535,BLNDL1360,BLNDL1341,BLNDL0945,BLNDL0940,BLNDL0882,BLNDL0726,BLNDL0635,BLNDL0595,BLNDL0419,BLNDL0251,BLNAS1501,BLNAS1379,BJLJL1377,BJLCC1224,BJLCC1187,BJLCC1169,BJLCC1159,BJLCC0976,BJLCC0913,BJLCC0798,BJLCC0743,BJLCC0295,BJBJ305,BJBJ300,BJBJ247,BJBJ245,BJBJ211,BJBJ202,BJBJ119,BJBJ114,BJBJ109,BJBJ090,BJBJ087,BJBJ082,BJBJ067,BJBJ066,BJBJ062,BJBJ057,BJBJ056,BJBJ054,BJBJ049,BJBJ048,BJBJ041,BJBJ038,BJBJ029,BJBJ027,BJBJ025,BJBJ011,BJBJ008,BJBJ007,BJBJ004,BJBJ002,BJBJ001,BHLJSH1548,BHLJMDJ1292,BHLJHEB1597,BHLJHEB1549,BHLJHEB1383,BHLJHEB1372,BHLJHEB1343,BHLJHEB1332,BHLJHEB0935,BHLJHEB0800,BHLJHEB0594,BHLJHEB0582,BHLJHEB0264,BHLJHEB0263,BHBXT0513,BHBSJZ1596,BHBSJZ1348,BHBSJZ1310,BHBSJZ1309,BHBSJZ1302,BHBSJZ1223,BHBSJZ1212,BHBSJZ0919,BHBSJZ0873,BHBSJZ0495,BHBSJZ0329,BHBSJZ0324,BHBQHD1436,BHBQHD0805,BHBQHD0585,BHBQHD0459,BHBHD1249,BHBCD1311,BHBBD0858,BHBBD0520,BHBBD0321,BGSLZ1616,BGSLZ1577,BGSLZ1428,BGSLZ1424,BGSLZ1307,BGSLZ1299,BGSLZ1173,BGSLZ0994,BGSLZ0979,BGSLZ0978,BGSLZ0956,BGSLZ0955,BGSLZ0933,BGSLZ0927,BGSLZ0812,BGSLZ0694,BGSLZ0576,BGSLZ0431,BGSLZ0402,BGSLZ0296,BGSLZ0014,BBSWH20019,BBSSH20007,BBSSH20001,BBSSCCD20015,BBSNSXTY10001,BBSLN20008,BBSLN20005,BBSJSSZ20001,BBSHEN20005,BBSHEB20004,BBSCQCQ20004,BBJBJ520,BBJBJ1621,BBJBJ1618,BBJBJ1583,BBJBJ1579,BBJBJ1556,BBJBJ1555,BBJBJ1554,BBJBJ1546,BBJBJ1545,BBJBJ1544,BBJBJ1528,BBJBJ1527,BBJBJ1520,BBJBJ1519,BBJBJ1494,BBJBJ1489,BBJBJ1487,BBJBJ1484,BBJBJ1482,BBJBJ1479,BBJBJ1478,BBJBJ1433,BBJBJ1432,BBJBJ1418,BBJBJ1397,BBJBJ1396,BBJBJ1386,BBJBJ1368,BBJBJ1338,BBJBJ1336,BBJBJ1329,BBJBJ1317,BBJBJ1316,BBJBJ1315,BBJBJ1265,BBJBJ1264,BBJBJ1255,BBJBJ1238,BBJBJ1191,BBJBJ1171,BBJBJ1145,BBJBJ1116,BBJBJ1093,BBJBJ1071,BBJBJ1054,BBJBJ1044,BBJBJ0985,BBJBJ0853,BBJBJ0838,BBJBJ0821,BBJBJ0802,BBJBJ0665,BBJBJ0638,BBJBJ0637,BBJBJ0611,BBJBJ0558,BBJBJ0557,BBJBJ0556,BBJBJ0552,BBJBJ0525,BBJBJ0482,BBJBJ0450,BBJBJ0006,ANWH026,ANWH024,ANWH023,ANWH022,ANWH020,ANWH019,ANWH011,ANWH006,ANWH004,ANWH003,ANTL008,ANMAS014,ANMAS013,ANMAS005,ANMAS001,ANLA010,ANLA006,ANLA004,ANLA003,ANHF063,ANHF062,ANHF061,ANHF060,ANHF059,ANHF058,ANHF057,ANHF056,ANHF055,ANHF053,ANHF051,ANHF049,ANHF048,ANHF047,ANHF044,ANHF042,ANHF039,ANHF035,ANHF034,ANHF026,ANHF019,ANHF013,ANHF010,ANHF008,ANFY034,ANFY032,ANFY002,AHWH028,AHWH027,AHSZ022,AHSZ009,AHHN022,AHHB100,AHBZ030,AHBB022,AHBB020,AHAQ007'
 
select * from dbo.STRING_SPLIT(@sql,',')
```

Comment: Much faster than the provided answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your database compatibility level is lower than **130**, SQL Server will not be able to find and execute `STRING_SPLIT` function. You can change a compatibility level of database using the following command:

```
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130
```

Note that compatibility level 120 might be default even in new **Azure SQL Databases.**

For reference:

**Version** - Highest Compatibility Level - Lowest Available Level

SQL 2017 - 140 - 100
SQL 2016 - 130 - 100
SQL 2014 - 120 - 100
SQL 2012 - 110 - 90
SQL 2008 - 100 - 80
SQL 2005 - 90 - 80
SQL 2000 - 80 - 80

Also, check your syntax as well like:

```
SELECT Value FROM STRING_SPLIT('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', ' ');
```

Comment: I try to alter my database but I don't have the permeation to do this change.
iam using sql server 2012 and I check my syntak there is no error.

Comment: No problem, check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database

Comment: Also, in order to alter stuff on your db, you require ALTER permissions.

Comment: In order to grant permissions to user: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-database-permissions-transact-sql

Comment: Ok Thank you

where can I found the implementation for this function if you know ?

Comment: You just need to do nothing but just GRANT permission to your database user and run the alter command as posted in my answer, you are good to go after that.

Comment: You are not answering the question

Answer (score -1):

I made this as a quick and dirty substitute using the table approach so the end user can select which of the sections they want. The original string can be used in a join or the individual row selected for a scalar result. Tested in

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-OD) (KB4091266) - 11.0.7469.6 (X64)   Feb 28 2018 17:47:20   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO

Create FUNCTION dbo.StringSplit2012
(
    @OriginalString VARCHAR(500)
 ,@Separator VARCHAR(6)
)
RETURNS @Sections TABLE
(
    OriginalString VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
 ,StringSection VARCHAR(500) NULL
 ,SectionNumber INT
)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @SectionCount INT;

```
    DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1;
    DECLARE @RemainingString VARCHAR(500);
    DECLARE @CurrentSection VARCHAR(500);


    SET @SectionCount =
        LEN (@OriginalString) - LEN (REPLACE (@OriginalString, @Separator, ''));
    IF @SectionCount = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO
                @Sections
                     (
                         OriginalString
                        ,StringSection
                        ,SectionNumber
                     )
            VALUES
                     (@OriginalString -- OriginalString - varchar(500)
                     ,@OriginalString -- StringSection - varchar(500)
                     ,1                             -- SectionNumber - int
                );
        END;

    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @RemainingString = @OriginalString;
            DECLARE @SectionStart INT;
            DECLARE @SectionLength INT;

            WHILE @LoopCounter <= @SectionCount
                BEGIN
                    SET @SectionStart = 1;
                    SET @SectionLength = CHARINDEX (@Separator, @RemainingString);

                    SET @CurrentSection = LEFT(@RemainingString, @SectionLength - 1);

                    INSERT INTO
                        @Sections
                             (
                                 OriginalString
                                ,StringSection
                                ,SectionNumber
                             )
                    VALUES
                             (@OriginalString
                             ,@CurrentSection
                             ,@LoopCounter  -- SectionNumber - int
                        );

                    SET @RemainingString =
                        RIGHT(@RemainingString, LEN (@RemainingString) - @SectionLength);

                    SET @LoopCounter = @LoopCounter + 1;


                END;
            DECLARE @TotalParsedLength INT =
            (
            SELECT SUM ( LEN (s.StringSection)) FROM @Sections AS    s
            ) + @SectionCount;
            SET @CurrentSection =
                RIGHT(@RemainingString, LEN (@OriginalString) - @TotalParsedLength);
            INSERT INTO
                @Sections
                     (
                         OriginalString
                        ,StringSection
                        ,SectionNumber
                     )
            VALUES
                     (@OriginalString
                     ,@CurrentSection
                     ,@LoopCounter  -- SectionNumber - int
                );
        END;



    RETURN;
END;
```

GO

I hope this saves someone some time. I use STRING_SPLIT in the function I created to give me the package name from a job step's command, and it blew up when I moved to my 2012 server. So I wrote my own. (Like ya do!)

Joey Morgan

BI/Integrations Developer III

Aspen Dental Management, Inc

Syracuse, NY