# Bulk insert sql server 2012 reading from array

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I Have this two array

```
DECLARE @ID NVARCHAR(300)= '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20';

DECLARE @Marks NVARCHAR(300)= '0,70,52,5,8,9,4,6,7,3,5,2,7,1,9,4,0,2,5,0';
```

## And I Have This Table

Grade

```
PersonId     Marks
1             10
2             9
3             15
4             26
```

I want to insert the values of the array to the table using BULK insert

how to do that ?

Comment: @YogeshSharma  I want to loads data from Array to the table

Comment: you could simply do that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902892/string-split-in-sql-server-2012 which is showing in example.

Comment: `Bulk Insert` - what exactly do you mean? This - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql or not?

Comment: @gotqn  yess I mean this

Comment: Could you show a little bit more from your file? I want to see its structure and how data is stored.

Comment: @gotqn  I don't want to load data from file ,I want to loads it from ther array

Answer (score 1):

Try the following `tsql` Query :-

```
DECLARE @ID NVARCHAR(300)= '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20';
DECLARE @Marks NVARCHAR(300)= '0,70,52,5,8,9,4,6,7,3,5,2,7,1,9,4,0,2,5,0';

INSERT INTO Grade (PersonId,Marks)
SELECT PersonId,
       Marks
FROM
(
    SELECT aSplit.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') PersonId,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY
                            (
                                SELECT 1
                            )) AS row_no
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@ID, ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS PersonId,
               CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@Marks, ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS Marks
    ) AS A
    CROSS APPLY PersonId.nodes('/X') AS aSplit(a)
) AS P
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT bSplit.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') Marks,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY
                            (
                                SELECT 1
                            )) AS row_no
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@ID, ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS PersonId,
               CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@Marks, ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS Marks
    ) AS A
    CROSS APPLY Marks.nodes('/X') AS bSplit(a)
) AS M ON P.row_no = M.row_no;
```

**Result :**

```
PersonId Marks
1        0
2        70
3        52
4        5
5        8
6        9
7        4
8        6
9        7
10       3
11       5
12       2
13       7
14       1
15       9
16       4
17       0
18       2
19       5
20       0
```

Comment: where is the bulk here ??

Comment: @Moh just uncomment the insert statement..., it will load the data from ur array in Grade table which u want.

Answer (score 0):

The [bulk insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) utility is used for importing data from external files, not SQL variables. If you are going to manipulated a large amount of data and you are concerned about performance you can read more about [database recovery models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server) where you can change your `Full` recovery model to `Bulk logged` for example.

I will advice to talk with superior before changing such settings in your are working in production environment.

Comment: Thanks for clarification
But my trainer asked me to import the data from array , and from 5 days ago I'm searching for a way to do that but I don't found any way to do that
@gotqn

Comment: So, your task is saying exactly that you have to use `BULK INSERT` and the data must be present in the `SQL Server` - you are not allowed to copy it in a file, for example?

Comment: @Moh Could you paste me the original text of the task. I am guessing you my not understand it correctly.

Comment: The task written in Arabic so I don't think you will understand it :D 

simply I have two array and I want to import the data from them to the table using BULK insert