# STRING_SPLIT from column value and reverse it in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to reverse string values in a column in SQL Server.

What I am trying to achieve is, when the value of the column is `child/parent`, I want to change it to `parent/child` when child  contains `'112'`

For example I want to change columns with value `Reports/112-Major` to `112-Major/Reports`

To start with, I tried to use `STRING_SPLIT` and append them like `String_Split(ColumnName,'/')[1] + String_Split(ColumnName,'/')[0]` if `String_Split(ColumnName,'/')[1]  like '%112%'`

[Most of the examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902892/string-split-in-sql-server-2012) that I see online have something like

```
SELECT Value FROM STRING_SPLIT('Lorem/ipsum/dolor/sit/amet.', '/');
```

But I want to split and then merge based on condition and then update the column

Something like,

```
update  tblTableName
set siteUrl = String_Split(ColumnName,'/')[1] + String_Split(ColumnName,'/')[0]
where `String_Split(ColumnName,'/')[1] like '%112%'
```

Is there a way to do this in SQL Server?

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected result..

Comment: thanks for asking. updated the question with one example. Please let me know if it helps

Answer (score 3):

You can use this expression:

```
stuff(col, 1, charindex('/', col), '') + '/' + left(col, charindex('/', col) - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option just for fun.

Gordon's solution would be my first choice and is certainly more performant (+1), but the following illustrates a simple technique which can be used to split a string into columns and not rows.

**Sample**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,YourCol varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'Reports/112-Major'),
(2,'Reports/Something Else')

Update @YourTable Set YourCol = Pos2+'/'+Pos1
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.YourCol,'/','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as B1 
             ) B
 Where Pos2 Like '%112%'
```

**Updated Results**

```
ID  YourCol
1   112-Major/Reports
2   Reports/Something Else
```