# SQL Server 2012 - Text Column - Splitting a column into multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following data:

> **ID |  First | Last |  Comments**
>
> 456|  John       |  Smith     | 1. alpha 2. bravo 3. charlie
>
> 132|  Tom        |  Ryan      | 1. zulu 2. yankee 3. xray

I am trying to format it as such:

> **ID |  First | Last |  Comments**
>
> 456|  John       |  Smith     | 1. alpha
>
> 456|  John       |  Smith     | 2. bravo
>
> 456|  John       |  Smith     | 3. charlie
>
> 132|  Tom        |  Ryan      | 1. zulu
>
> 132|  Tom        |  Ryan      | 2. yankee
>
> 132|  Tom        |  Ryan      | 3. xray

Because each comment is a different length I cannot use a function like LEFT(). The comments are always preceded by the number and a period however there are 30 comments per person. This lead me to CHARINDEX() and it seemed I could build a CASE statement with it, however because the data type for the Comments column is Text, CHARINDEX() won't work. Is there a workaround to separate this column?

Comment: There are workarounds, but a true **fix** for this would be to normalize your data. Storing delimited strings in a column, as you have discovered, is a real pain to work with. Any chance you can change that?

Comment: You might be able to use STRING_SPLIT - which would really make your life easier.  Otherwise, you will want to implement a function.  There are several approaches - tally table, xml, and recursive cte are the methods I can think of off the top of my head.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902892/string-split-in-sql-server-2012

Comment: @RyanB. not in 2012 unfortunately but [this is a good alternative](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).

Comment: @scsimon Unfortunately the database is the back-end of an application. I couldn't say why anyone used Text!