# Split a string with varying factors in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have serialized data stored in a column. I want to convert list values to a temp table. But there are more than one factors in row values like

```
["2","3","4"]
[&quot;1&quot;,&quot;2&quot;,&quot;3&quot;]
[]
["Select option B","Select option C","Select option D"]
["Moderate","Heavy","Heavy, Big & Abnormal"]
```

If I parse out double quotes then comma in string value will create that as different entity.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tagged with `[sql-server-2012]` - what a pity... With v2016+ you could call for `STRING_SPLIT` or even JSON methods... The following is a rather hacky approach but works - at least with your provided test data...

Create a *mockup-table* (please do this yourself the next time).

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourString VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('["2","3","4"]')
,('[&quot;1&quot;,&quot;2&quot;,&quot;3&quot;]')
,('[]')
,('["Select option B","Select option C","Select option D"]')
,('["Moderate","Heavy","Heavy, Big & Abnormal"]');
```

--This is the query:

```
SELECT t.ID
      --,t.YourString 
      ,C.Separated.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Parted
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(YourString,'&quot;','"'),'["',''),'"]','')) A(replaced)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT A.replaced [*] FOR XML PATH('')),'","','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) B(casted)
CROSS APPLY B.casted.nodes('/x') C(Separated);
```

The idea in short:

First of all I use multiple `REPLACE()` to clean and harmonise your data. The second `CROSS APPLY` will then use XML to split up your strings by **replacing each comma together with the quotes!** with XML tags. Thus we can prevent splitting at internal commas. But before, we have to use `FOR XML` on the orginal string, to allow characters such as the `&` in `Big & Abnormal`. The rest ist rather easy `XPath/XQuery`.

The result

```
+----+-----------------------+
| ID | Parted                |
+----+-----------------------+
| 1  | 2                     |
+----+-----------------------+
| 1  | 3                     |
+----+-----------------------+
| 1  | 4                     |
+----+-----------------------+
| 2  | 1                     |
+----+-----------------------+
| 2  | 2                     |
+----+-----------------------+
| 2  | 3                     |
+----+-----------------------+
| 3  | []                    |
+----+-----------------------+
| 4  | Select option B       |
+----+-----------------------+
| 4  | Select option C       |
+----+-----------------------+
| 4  | Select option D       |
+----+-----------------------+
| 5  | Moderate              |
+----+-----------------------+
| 5  | Heavy                 |
+----+-----------------------+
| 5  | Heavy, Big & Abnormal |
+----+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `STRING_SPLIT` with ordinality:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT value AS val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0) AS ord
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(TRIM('[]' FROM '["2","3","4"]'), ',')
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT value AS val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0) AS ord
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(TRIM('[]' FROM '["Select option B","Select option C","Select option D"]'), ',')
)
-- ...
SELECT cte.val, cte2.val
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN cte2
  ON cte.ord = cte2.ord
-- ...
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=11520f00faf8bb08c8a972de5817b4a9)**

For SQL Server you could use user defined split function: [STRING_SPLIT in SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902892/string-split-in-sql-server-2012)

Comment: The OP tag SQL Server 2012, and it's `STRING_SPLIT()` not `SPLIT_STRING()`

Comment: OK, the idea is still the same, OP could use any split function available for SQL Server 2012.

Comment: The problem is when I put comma as a separator, it fails on values which have comma in strings