# How to parse XML ordred list into table view

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

How to parse ***XML ordered list*** like this

```
<ol>
  <li>value1</li>
  <li>value2</li>
  <li>value3</li>
</ol>
```

into table like this (like it's visible in html):

```
Nr          Value
----------- ------
1           value1
2           value2
3           value3
```

Here is the code for XML string:

```
declare @ol XML= '<ol><li>'+REPLACE('value1,value2,value3', ',', '</li><li>')+'</li></ol>' 
select  @ol
```

**NB!** Is it possible to parse "numbering" from XML without creating something like `identity` column?

***Small update:***
Following solutions provide right answer for simple example above:

1. [Yitzhak Khabinsky, Salman A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58522693/6165594)
2. [akhilesh singh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58523641/6165594)

But is it possible to get solution for this more tricky example:

```
DECLARE @ol XML 
SET @ol= 
'<ol type="i" start="3">
  <li>value1</li>
  <li>value2</li>
  <li>value3</li>
</ol>';
```

Estimated result:

```
Nr   Value
---- -------
iii  value1
iv   value2
v    value3
```

?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you had a look at `XQUERY`? There's plenty of examples on SO on how to read the `xml` datatype in SQL Server; what answers didn't you understand so we can explain them to you. Thanks,

Comment: Is the order important e.g. is it OK to have `1, value3` in result instead of `1, value1`?

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, it's very important

Comment: @Denis...i have edited my answer you can check out...

Answer (score 2):

Finding the nodes is easy, finding their relative position is tricky. Here is one solution by using what is called *Node Comparison operation* via `<<` operator and `count` function:

```sql
DECLARE @ol XML = '<ol>
  <li>value1</li>
  <li>value2</li>
  <li>value3</li>
</ol>';
SELECT li.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS value
     , li.value('let $n := . return count(../*[. << $n]) + 1', 'int') AS pos
FROM @ol.nodes('/ol/li') AS x(li)
```

Comment: Thank you guys, for this "crazy" example. :)   Your solution works for any element. Is it possible for code to take into account that it's a specific elements `ol` `li` and read some "metadata"?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you're trying to match a specific `ol` e.g. `<ol class="foo">` then simply use the selector `/ol[@class="foo"]/li`

Comment: I updated the post: put the link to your solution in my question and add one more tricky question/example. Do you have a solution for it?

Comment: @Denis the `type` and `start` attributes are only understood and rendered by a browser. XML does not know what these HTML attributes mean. It is possible to read the start attribute and add it to each number (1 becomes 3, 2 becomes 4) but I am not sure how to convert numbers to roman numerals. And then you have `type=a` as well.

Comment: ok, let's view from other angle: is it possible to organize numbering in XML without using `<ol>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ol XML 
SET @ol= '<ol>
  <li>value1</li>
  <li>value2</li>
  <li>value3</li>
</ol>';

SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Nr,
li.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS Value
FROM @ol.nodes('/ol/li') AS x(li)
```

Try this Simple Query...here...Getting Row Number ()...so we get Nr as Number...1,2,3..so on...and xml value into table....

You will get this type of Output...

**Output :**

```
Nr          Value
----------- ------
1           value1
2           value2
3           value3
```

After Edit Your Question...the Solution Should be Like this.....

```
DECLARE @ol XML 
SET @ol= 
'<ol type="i" start="3">
  <li>value1</li>
  <li>value2</li>
  <li>value3</li>
</ol>';

SELECT 2 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Nr,
li.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS Value
FROM @ol.nodes('/ol/li') AS x(li)
```

**Output :**

```
Nr          Value
----------- ------
3           value1
4           value2
5           value3
```

here adding +2 value to RowNumber() so....we can get the value 2,3,4...and so on..

Comment: Are you sure if it's the deterministic solution? For example, Are you sure that for value1 I always get Nr 1, not something else (especially in big lists)?

Comment: No...No....it will generate the row number....1,2,3...and must be go on...not depends on value1 or value2

Comment: Thank you. I updated the post: put the link to your solution in my question and add one more tricky question/example. Do you have a solution for it?

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` will generate an arbitrary row number. You have no guarantee that `Value1` will always get 1 as it's row number. read [The “Natural order” misconception](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/08/the-natural-order-misconception/)

Comment: @akhileshsingh unfortunately as @Zohar Peled mentioned above it's not safe to use `ROW_NUMBER()` for this purpose.