# SQL: Count of items in comma-separated column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

```
Column1
--------
1,2,4
2,3,5
2,1,3
```

I have a column in a table which is comma-separated as shown above. From which I need to get below output:

```
No   Count
----------
1     2
2     3
3     2
4     1
```

When I tried with

```
SELECT SUM(LEN(Holidays) - LEN(REPLACE(Holidays, ',', '')) + 1)  
FROM [dbo].[OhLog]
```

I'm not getting item wise count. Instead it is getting full count.

Comment: Sql Server 2017

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `CROSS_APPLY` with [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to create rows from the comma separated data values, and then `COUNT` the occurrences of each value:

```
SELECT value as [Holiday], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM OhLog
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([Holidays], ',')
GROUP BY value
```

Output:

```
Holiday     Count
1           2
2           3
3           2
4           1
5           1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=388b44bb4f13e0bf98d437fd08164dde)

If your database compatibility version is not at least 130, you won't have access to `STRING_SPLIT`. You can modify the compatibility version as described in the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15), or alternatively, use this query (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902892/string-split-in-sql-server-2012)):

```
SELECT [Holiday], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM (SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') [Holiday]
      FROM (SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE([Holidays], ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
            FROM Ohlog
     ) AS A
     CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a)) AS O
GROUP BY [Holiday]
```

Output is the same as for the prior query. [Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a8bc5e300efef790693cb2995ea5b825)

Comment: It is showing this message 'Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT''

Comment: @LimnaD'silva what is the compatibility level of your database? It needs to be at least 130 to use `STRING_SPLIT`. If it's below that, can you adjust it? See the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15). If you're running SQL Server 2017, it should be 140...

Comment: @LimnaD'silva see my edit, I've added a solution which should work for lower compatibility version databases.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    Num, count(*) Cnt from
(
    SELECT 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Num
    FROM
    (
    SELECT CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(Column1,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
    FROM   tbl
    )t
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
)x
GROUP BY Num
```

[Demo Result](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=044fc5106130ede536cd207da2c0ebd1)

Answer (score 0):

So, you can use STRING_SPLIT function. It is supported by Sql Server 2017.
more info here http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-string-functions/sql-server-string_split-function/

It creates a table from string.

So, for each row in DB you will get a table. To Union it into one common table you have to use CROSS APPLY.

```
SELECT VALUE, COUNT(*) FROM test_for_parse CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(array_value,',') GROUP BY VALUE
```

So, here is an example of code, that emulate your situation.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8393f8dab667b528ed5aad7c61da74fe