# how to pass multiple date values to a single variable in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

Unable to pass multiple date value.

```
declare @Exdate date
set @Exdate = '2020-2-26','2020-2-27'

select * 
from X 
where Ex_Date in (@Exdate)
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call split function  :

```
select x.* 
from X cross apply
     dbo.splitfn(@Exdate, ',') as spt(dateval)
where x.Ex_Date = dateval;
```

Your variable (`@Exdate`) should have single string not multiple :

```
set @Exdate = '2020-2-26, 2020-2-27'
```

Comment: here the possibility is like the date value may be a single date or multiple. Function needs to work for single date too

Comment: @DineshkumarMohan. . . Yes.

Comment: @DineshkumarMohan. . . It is pseudo function name, need to change your function name. However, `2016 +` has default split function. You can use it.

Comment: @DineshkumarMohan. . . Then look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902892/string-split-in-sql-server-2012/46902994#46902994

Comment: i am using MSSQLServer2012

Answer (score 0):

Is you need different datetime values, you can declare table variable:

```
declare @Exdate table (
 date_value date
)
insert into @Exdate (date_value)
values ('2020-2-26'),('2020-2-27')
select *
from X where Ex_date in (select date_values from @Exdate)
```