# Replacing a string pattern - SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a VARCHAR Column called CompanyInformation that contains some Json data inside of it, here is a example of what is being stored inside of this column.

```
{
"tradeName": "example",
"corporateName": "example",
"phone": "example",
"nationalExpansions": [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "nameFranchise": "example",
        "phoneNumber": "example",
        "mobileNumber": "example",
        "email": "example@example.com.br"
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "nameFranchise": "example",
        "phoneNumber": "example",
        "mobileNumber": "example",
        "email": "example"
    },
```

What i have to do is replace all emails inside of this file to one specific email, i was trying to use the `REPLACE` function to do that, but i don`t know exactly how to do pattern matching in SQL.

```
UPDATE MyExampleTable SET CompanyInformation = REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CompanyInformation), '"email": "%%"', '"email": "tests@gmail.com.br"')
```

But it doesn't work, the UPDATE gets executed, but he never replace the email information because he doesn't find any matching pattern.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with? for 2016 or higher, you might be able to use the built in Json_update function.

Comment: Its a older version

Comment: Unfortunately SQL Server has no pattern replacement functionality. It does have Pattern Matching, however that tells you were the start of the pattern is, and not where it ends. For a pattern that uses variable length wildcards, that may mean what you want isn't (easily) achievable. You may well be better off looking for a CLR REGEX function for this.

Comment: So, which version of SQL Server are you using? Unfortunately, STRING_SPLIT is available from Version 2016 and up only (as far as I know)... anyways, XML might do the trick. See the following thread for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902892/string-split-in-sql-server-2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and thanks to the help of a teammate, we've managed to find a solution to this problem, so i will post here to help anyone with the same problem.

This is the script:

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @start INT = 0
DECLARE @begin INT = 0
DECLARE @end INT = 0
DECLARE @Id INT

DECLARE curEmail CURSOR
FOR
SELECT Id, CompanyInformation
FROM MyExampleTable
--WHERE id = 1

OPEN curEmail

FETCH NEXT FROM curEmail INTO @Id, @text

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @start = CHARINDEX('"email":"', @text) + 9;

    SET @begin = @start

    WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        --print 'end='+cast(@end as varchar(4))
        SELECT @start = CHARINDEX('"email":"', @text, @end) + 9;

        IF @begin <= @start
            SET @begin = @start
        ELSE
            BREAK
        SELECT @end = CHARINDEX('"', @text, @start)

        SET @text = STUFF(@text, @start, @end - @start, 'tests@gmail.com.br')

    END

    print @text
    update MyExampleTable set CompanyInformation= @text where id =@id

    FETCH NEXT FROM curEmail INTO @Id, @text

END

CLOSE curEmail

DEALLOCATE curEmail
```