# Splitting columns over multiple rows - String_Split does not work

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, split

I have the following code:

```
select *
from (
    select aTable.cas_id,  aTable.udv_string
    from bTable, aTable
    where bTable.field_id = '50'
    and bTable.field_id = aTable.field_id
) infotable
```

This gives the following output:

```
cas_id    udv_string
582       2    4
615       2
276       23
453       2    4
1004      2    4
```

As you can see, three rows have multiple values which are space separated.  I have tried to use 'split_string' but this doesn't work for me.  Can someone please help? I have also searched and tried to apply the solutions on your stackoverflow sites regarding this problem to no avail.

I would like the output to be:

```
cas_id   udv_string
582      2
582      4
615      2
276      23
453      2
453      4
1004     2
1004     4
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: What is the problem with `STRING_SPLIT()` (not `split_string`)?

Comment: add a sample data that will help

Comment: I meant string_split() won't work. The object is not recognised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with `SQL Server 16 +` then you can use `string_split()` :

```
select a.cas_id, aa.value as udv_string
from aTable a inner join
     bTable b
     on b.field_id = a.field_id cross apply
     string_split(a.udv_string, '  ') aa
where a.field_id = 50;
```

**Note** : I have used standar explicit join syntax instead of comma separated.

For older version you can reffer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902892/string-split-in-sql-server-2012/46902994#46902994).

Comment: Thanks for the help Yogesh!  I really appreciate it.  That took me hours and I could not work out why string_split() would not work