# Separate a value from string in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Here is my string/column value:

`ReferenceId=678&MobileNo=226789&Pnumber=9878&SIB=121314&.........&PIN=34&....`

There are so many fields. I am interested in above mentioned field.
How to separate/fetch value of them in SQL Server 2012? The `string_split()` function is not supported in 2012.

Comment: you can substring function of sql server just like below.                           select SUBSTRING(input_string, start, length);

Comment: take reference https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp

Comment: Why did you tag this as ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create the `UFN_STRING_SPLIT` function suggested by @Dave here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63293980/8286724)

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[UFN_STRING_SPLIT]
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a 
      CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
```

test your code:

```
select
    Left(Item, charindex('=', Item, 0) - 1) as FielName,
    right(Item, len(Item) - charindex('=', Item, 0)) as [Value]
from
    dbo.UFN_STRING_SPLIT('ReferenceId=678&MobileNo=226789&Pnumber=9878&SIB=121314', '&')
```

Comment: Hello Eliseu,that help me lot.But how find whose value is what.Like 678 is ReferenceId and Pnumber is 9878.How to store in variable.Because want to use this in further processing

Comment: Hi @smita! I just updated the answer, in the part where the `UFN_STRING_SPLIT` function is called, now the query returns `FielName` and `Value`.