# Split column values in a table separated with special character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, sql-server-2012

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Table 1

+----+--------+----------+
| ID | Name   |   SIZE   |      
+----+--------+----------+
| 1  | Style1 | S,M,L,XL |  
+----+--------+----------+
```

I need to iterate through the whole table and load it into another table that looks like the following without using `SPLIT_STRING`, we are using  SQL Server 2012 without that capability.

I also know that the max values that would be inserted into the new table would be 100 columns wide. I'm still new to SQL and not very comfortable with functions and how to utilize them.

```
Table 2

+----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-------+
| ID |  NAME  | SIZE1 | SIZE2 | SIZE3 | SIZE4 | ... | SIZEN |
+----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-------+
|  1 | Style1 | S     | M     | L     | XL    |     |       |
+----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-------+
```

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [STRING\_SPLIT in SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902892/string-split-in-sql-server-2012)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are stuck with Sql Server 2012 you can use a bit of XML syntax.

This is a sample of code that should help you:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE (
    [id] INT
    ,[Name] VARCHAR(max)
    ,[Size] VARCHAR(max)
    );

INSERT INTO @mockup
VALUES (
    1,'Style'
    ,'S,M,L,XL'
    )

;WITH Splitted
AS (
    SELECT [id]
        ,[Name]
        ,[Size]
        ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE([Size], ',', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Parts
    FROM @mockup
    )
SELECT [id]
    ,[Name]
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[1]', 'varchar(5)') AS Column_1
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[2]', 'varchar(5)') AS Column_2
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[3]', 'varchar(5)') AS Column_3
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[4]', 'varchar(5)') AS Column_4
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[5]', 'varchar(5)') AS Column_5
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[6]', 'varchar(5)') AS Column_6
    --and so on until column 100
FROM Splitted;
```

Results:

[image]

Basically the code above transforms the content of your `Size` column into an xml fragment:

```
<x>S</x><x>M</x><x>L</x><x>XL</x>
```

Then you can extract each value in a different column using `value()` xml method (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)).

Comment: Hi Andrea! how do i move the data into a XML format! thank you for all your help

Comment: @ClaudeSAugilar the code I posted already does the conversion (in the `CAST(... AS XML)` statement). I edited my answer to clarify that the phrase about xml conversion is just an explanation of how the code works.

Comment: thank you for your help! it worked I'm very excited

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this--especially where the size column count varies--is with dynamic SQL. Here's an example I put together you can run in SSMS. It takes some of the same principles that @Andrea mentioned and expands on it.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Sizes TABLE ( Id INT, Name VARCHAR(50), Sizes VARCHAR(50) );
INSERT INTO @Sizes ( Id, Name, Sizes ) VALUES
    ( 1, 'Style1', 'S,M,L,XL');

DECLARE @dynamic_sql VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @dynamic_sql = 'SELECT '
    +  CAST ( [Id] AS VARCHAR(10) ) + ' AS [ID],'
    + '''' + [Name] + ''' AS [NAME],'
    + List.Cols + ';'
FROM @Sizes
OUTER APPLY ( 
    SELECT CAST ( '<sizes><size>' + REPLACE ( Sizes, ',', '</size><size>' ) + '</size></sizes>' AS XML ) SizeXml
) AS x
OUTER APPLY (

    SELECT STUFF ( (

        SELECT
            ', ''' + Size + ''' AS [SIZE' + CAST ( SizeId AS VARCHAR(10) ) + ']' AS "text()"
        FROM (

            SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) ) AS SizeId,
                n.s.value ( '.', 'VARCHAR(50)' ) AS Size 
            FROM x.SizeXml.nodes('//sizes/size') n ( s )

        ) AS xml_list FOR XML PATH ('')

    ), 1, 2, '' ) AS Cols

) AS List
WHERE Id = 1;

-- Execute the dynamic SQL statement.
EXEC ( @dynamic_sql );
```

Returns

```
+----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID |  NAME  | SIZE1 | SIZE2 | SIZE3 | SIZE4 |
+----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | Style1 | S     | M     | L     | XL    |
+----+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: thank you for your help! it worked I'm very excited

Comment: @ClaudeSAugilar I'm glad I could help. Please mark as the accepted answer if I did in fact answer your need.