Recreating the InitCap or Proper function with some restrictions
First of all I am using this SQL Server version according to @@version:
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4583465) - 11.0.7507.2 (X64) - Nov 1 2020 00:48:37   
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

As the title says, I am trying to recreate the Oracle SQL InitCap() or the Excel's Proper() function, which provide proper capitalization for strings:
initcap("THis iS a STRIng") 

returns:      This Is A String
But here are the system restrictions:

I am using SQL Server 2012, so I cannot use newer functions such as String_Split.
Very restricted environment does not let me use the CREATE functions, so no functions, procedures, etc.

It would need these features:

Properly capitalize each first letter for each word in a string field while changing the rest to lower case, as most likely the whole string could be uppercase. Words that start with numbers (i.e. 234name) should capitalize the first letter (234Name).

Optional: accommodate for company names with apostrophes, or words that start with "Mc" (i.e. MCDONALD should result in McDonald). Maybe have an IN() section where I can add more exceptions.

Nice to have: section that would allow me to specify stand alone exceptions such as "LLC" (When being a stand alone word that gets changed to "Llc").


So I would need to the code to be included in a SELECT statement:
SELECT
    NumericField1 AS "Number Field",
    (Smart Code Provided By StackOverFLow User(StringField1)) AS "Customer Name",
...
FROM 
    DataBaseTable

Can this be accomplished?
I have tried other options suggested here, but unfortunately I can not use functions (the CREATE command actually) and this environment uses Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR), so I cannot use newer keywords that were also suggested.

Also SQL Server reached End of Life about 2 years ago; you really need to get your finalised upgrade plan (from 3+ years ago) implemented. Using unsupported, and insecure, software is a vulnerability for both you and your clients.

You can emulate STRING_SPLIT by using FOR XML tricks or recursive CTEs (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902892/string-split-in-sql-server-2012). SO is not a free code writing service either, so you need to demostrate some effort here as well as a lot of test data, especially when you use such obsolete version.

Can't provide a lot of detail, but we use a query overlay system that uses SQL Server 2012. I cannot change that.

This sounds like a task for the presentation layer however, not the SQL Layer.

Unfortunately, the presentation layer does not have that capability, hence my question.

SQL Server doesn't have that capability (built-in) either, though, your programming layer is likely much better at doing the task still.

Does your layer and i use the term loosely support CTEs at least?

On a separate notes things like "Hello Ladies and Gentlemen:" are intentionally relieved from posts as they are seen as "noise"; please don't re-add it to posts after others remove it.

It's not impossible. Whether it's worth the trouble is another story:
select s3
from t cross apply (values (
    replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
    replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
        '<<<< ' + s + ' >>>>',
        '0', '0!@# '), '1', '1!@# '), '2', '2!@# '), '3', '0!@# '), '4', '4!@# '),
        '5', '5!@# '), '6', '6!@# '), '7', '7!@# '), '8', '8!@# '), '9', '9!@# ')
    )) as step1(s1) cross apply (values (
    replace(replace(
    replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
    replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
    replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
    replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
        replace(lower(s1), ' mc', ' Mc!@# '), 
        ' a', ' A'), ' b', ' B'), ' c', ' C'), ' d', ' D'), ' e', ' E'), ' f', ' F'),
        ' g', ' G'), ' h', ' H'), ' i', ' I'), ' j', ' J'), ' k', ' K'), ' l', ' L'),
        ' m', ' M'), ' n', ' N'), ' o', ' O'), ' p', ' P'), ' q', ' Q'), ' r', ' R'),
        ' s', ' S'), ' t', ' T'), ' u', ' U'), ' v', ' V'), ' w', ' W'), ' x', ' X'),
        ' y', ' Y'), ' z', ' Z')
    )) as step2(s2) cross apply (values (
    replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
        s2, '!@# ', ''), ' And ', ' and '), ' Llc ', ' LLC '), '<<<< ', ''), ' >>>>', '')
    )) as step3(s3);

I couldn't test on SQL Server 2012 but it does collapse all the cross apply steps into a single nested Compute Scalar operation at least as far back as 2014. So I'm not sure it really benefits from being broken up other than for ease of amending it. My original intent was hoping to avoid reworking the query if there was a function nesting limit that I didn't remember off the top of my head. The limit did in fact appear to be 244 levels going back about a decade. Ultimately that means that the entire expression can be dropped in in much the desired form OP suggested. (Refer to fiddle to see the expanded version.)
The string '!@#' is used as a marker for a location that had a space inserted that needs to be removed. So the assumption is that there would be a similar sequence you can reliably assume would never appear in real data. '<<<<' and '>>>>' do essentially the same thing.
This does preserve leading and trailing spaces. As written it would not capitalize any characters adjacent to punctuation or handle LLC.
https://dbfiddle.uk/HpABNDs5
This has some better handling of apostrophes:
https://dbfiddle.uk/RTLkRHnU

That's honestly pretty neat!


Can this be accomplished?

Under those restrictions, it cannot reasonably be done.
